# Adding text on Revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode, revolution-slider, text-rotation

I am using Revolution slider plugin for a wordpress site. The slider gives the option to add text on slider image But I want to add a rotate text on the slider image which is possible by using a plugin shortcode.

Do you have any idea where i can put shortcode for text so that it works upon Revolution slider image?

I'm using this text rotator plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/saeid-simple-text-rotator/

I have tried to put the shortcode after the slider shortcode but it displays next to the slider area.

Please help me if you have any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra plugin to do this.

1. Add the (text)element
2. Click on animations
3. Select the "+" icon
4. Click on rotation
5. Edit the rotations

Now you're able to set the rotations for the element. I will upload a screenshot, but its in Dutch.

[image]